# node and nginx how to find static files?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to host different applications in digitalocean using node/express/nginx

I also have a Meteor application running as the main route

Here's my nginx `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /buscatucanal {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


}
```

the first one `/` works normally but `/buscatucanal` isn't finding the css/images/js.

Here's the `express` js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/buscatucanal', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(4000, function(){
 console.log("listening in port 4000");
});
```

and here's a few of the static files the `index.html` file is looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="buscatucanal/public2/js/app.js"></script>
```

and here are the error logs from developer tools:

```
GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css 
buscatucanal:9 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css 
buscatucanal:145 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 
buscatucanal:13 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/css/custom.css 
buscatucanal:147 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js 
buscatucanal:146 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js 
buscatucanal:148 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js 
buscatucanal:149 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js 
buscatucanal:152 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/js/app.js 
buscatucanal:43 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/images/logo1.png 404 (Not Found)
buscatucanal:150 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.js 
buscatucanal:151 GET http://myipaddress/buscatucanal/public2/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**

I change the `index.html` file and edit the files it's looking for like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public2/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it works if I go directly to the port like `http://myipaddress:4000` it works perfectly.

But when I go like `http://myipaddress/buscatucanal` I get different errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myipaddress/public2/bower_components/angular-material-data-table/dist/md-data-table.min.css".
buscatucanal:9 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myipaddress/public2/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css".
buscatucanal:13 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myipaddress/public2/css/custom.css".
```

And it seems like it's not serving them right:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mime type.

I'm assuming you've included mime types in Nginx properly, on my machine I've got this..

```
http {
     include       mime.types;
     default_type  application/octet-stream;
```

You're not setting the mime type in your code. Have a look in the express docs

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

> ```
> res.type(type)
> ```
>
> Sets the Content-Type HTTP header to the MIME type as determined by 
>   mime.lookup() for the specified type. If type contains the “/”
>   character, then it sets the Content-Type to type.

```
res.type('.html');              // => 'text/html'
res.type('html');               // => 'text/html'
res.type('json');               // => 'application/json'
res.type('application/json');   // => 'application/json'
res.type('png');                // => image/png
```

There's a module called mime `mime.lookup` that you can use to get the MIME type

https://github.com/broofa/node-mime?_ga=1.178625127.213417936.1460395729#mimelookuppath

```
mime.lookup('/path/to/file.txt');         // => 'text/plain'
mime.lookup('file.txt');                  // => 'text/plain'
mime.lookup('.TXT');                      // => 'text/plain'
mime.lookup('htm');
```

Node can also set the header explicitly.